# Is it a good practice to store auth session in the database?

Tags: mysql

I created a login system that in addition to being used on a website, will also be used in mobile applications.

As on cell phones I want to keep the user logged in until he chooses to log out, I did not use the authentication for sessions in PHP.

So I thought it would be better to store the login sessions in the database, for each user request, to verify if the authentication token is still valid.

But I don't know if this is a good practice. Since every time the user updates the screen in the browser, or sends any application request to the system, he will make a query to verify that the login is still active and then make another query to search for what the user requested.

My concern is whether this will become too slow, for a system that could have between 900 million and 1,5 billion users, since the database will have many more requests and verification queries in addition to the normal query requested by the user.

Below is the current structure of my database. I would also like tips if my structure is very wrong.

[image: MysqlDatabase]

Comment: With sys_users_sessions, `varbinary` avoid character set considerations especially on the primary key. Make sure it has a primary key. Do you really need all those fields? But mainly, don't assume it will be to slow, benchmark it, either a database directly (e.g. sysbench) on the queries per sessions or any web benchmark (e.g. jmeter) application.

Comment: @danblack Thanks for the tips with `varbinary` and benchmark. I will do that. About primary key: `logintoken` is the **primary key** of the sys_user_sessions table. Because it is through it that the system always checks if the user is logged in, and it is unique for each device that the user logs in to. About needing all the fields: for the `sys users` table they are not all necessary, I can decrease if this is bad. But in the `sys_users_sessions` table, yes, all are necessary as it is for security and administration support.